# QAF Framework-Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium, qaf

Env:
QAF
, Java
, TestNG
, Appium
, IVY

Am using QAF along with BDDTestFactory.
I upgraded Eclipse from Java Developers IDE to Neon.
Then after doing all the set-up including downloading dependencies, I am seeing this error.
[image]

Comment: Are you able to run test using ant or maven? If so something wrong with eclipse testng plug-in.

Comment: we are using IVY as the dependency management tool.

Comment: Are you able to run test using ant build file?

Comment: Please help, Seeing: [ivy:resolve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:resolve]  SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]  SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar
[ivy:resolve]  SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.pom
[ivy:resolve]  SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar

Comment: You may update http to https and try.

Comment: This is after changing http to https in seleniumtestrunner.xml. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Finally I am able to resolve ivy dependency issues mentioned above & I am able to run the tests through ant script . Can you provide a solution/workaround with the above problem I am facing with Testng?

Comment: Logged a defect on TestNG & this is the response I got from one of the contributor "There is no workaround that I can think of because the problem for sure is not in TESTNG. It's a case of messed up CLASSPATH.". Can you please look into this & provide a proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

After spending considerable time, finally, got to know the solution. The real culprit was the Eclipse version. It was Eclipse neon that was being used which was actually released in 2016 & was quite old. The Eclipse was upgraded from "Neon" to "2020-06" & after that everything worked smoothly. But still the compatible TestNG version for QAF framework is 6.10.

Just for the benefit of others, if we directly download the link 'Mac OS X (Cocoa) 64-bit' displayed under 'Download Links' on the right side here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/neon/3/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers, it actually downloads Eclipse Neon Version.

If you carefully notice at the top there is a info message "This package was released on 03/23/2017. A newer package is available here." and in this message if you click on the word 'here', you will actually be navigated to all the latest versions of Eclipse.
I just thought(in-fact I was deceived) the most stable version is actually listed directly to the users and I downloaded Neon. Please don't repeat the same mistake.

It seems like Eclipse wants us to download and use Eclipse installer. So, first they are directing us to a page where we actually see older version of Eclispe. If at all we click the link as mentioned above, then we are navigated to a page where they have displayed a banner to download Eclipse installer along with the latest versions of Eclipse.